# JAX: How to accumulate jnp.array on a condition in a jit function?

Tags: python, jit, jax

I want to filter a jnp.array with a condition, and accumulate to a global variable, in a jit function (so we have to use JAX control flow primitives):

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit
from jax import lax

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)


@jit
def get_data():
  data = jax.random.normal(key, (5, 3))
  data = data.at[-2:].set(0.)
  return data


data = get_data()
accu = data[0]


@jit
def filter(data):
  def body_fun(i):
    global accu
    accu = jnp.vstack((accu, data[i]))
    return i + 1

  lax.while_loop(lambda i: jnp.all(data[i]), body_fun, 1)

filter(data)
```

I expect `accu.shape` is (3,3) (there are three non-zero rows in data) after `filter` executed, but got (2,3):

```
Traced<ShapedArray(float32[2,3])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/1)>
```

I suspect `lax.while_loop` iterates row 1 and 2, but global accu only got updated once, but why? Or is there any better way to accumulate jnp.array (in jit function) without using global variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your `body_fun` updates `accu` by using a side-effect. Jax is a functional programming library: you'll want to make all the updates explicit. Meaning that `accu` should be in the arguments of `body_fun` and also returned by it after being updated.

The signature of `jax.lax.while_loop` is `jax.lax.while_loop(cond_fun, body_fun, init_val)`. In your case, `init_val` should be the tuple `(counter, accu)`.

The last issue is that `accu` should be of fixed shape. You'll want to initialize it beforehand to some shape, which in your case will be an upper bound on the shape of the final `accu`.

In the end, the following code works. Here, I suggest to not close over `data`, to make it obvious that `cond_fn` depends on data too. You could have a closure instead.

```py
# Initialization
data = get_data()
accu = jax.zeros_like(data)
i = 0

def body_fn(carry): 
    i, accu, data = carry
    accu = accu.at[i].set(data[i])
    return (i + 1, accu, data)

def cond_fn(carry):
    i, accu, data = carry
    return jnp.all(data[i])

last_i, accu, _ = lax.while_loop(body_fn, (i, accu))
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I realized that "be side-effect free means fixed shape" after a few experiments (and answered someone's q: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949439/742634). 
So the fix should be:
`accu = jnp.empty_like(data)`
in def body_fn(x):
`accu = accu.at[i].set(data[i])` and `return (i + 1, accu)`

Comment: Precisely; updating my answer to make the code readily available.